# Azure App services Error: Reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: azure, web, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I get this error when I run an app I deployed to the Azure App services The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application. Driving me crazy. I don't know what the reply URL should be.

Comment: I should have said it authenticates against Azure AD first and then doesn't know how to get back to the URL

Comment: Ive faced a similar error.  Annoying for sure. Can you share some obfuscated details?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when the real redirect_uri doesn't match the reply url in Azure portal. You can track the auth request url to find the real redirect_uri. The request url is something like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345
```

You will find the request url in the sign in page.

[image]

Just get the **redirect_uri** in the request url, make sure it is the same as the one you configured in azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting this error and it's driving me crazy because it works fine on Microsoft Edge but won't work on Chrome, IE, Safari, etc.

Very strange. Can you confirm you're getting this issue on Microsoft Edge (New Engine, not the old one)

I've opened a ticket with Azure Support, they should have a log to break down where and why this error is occurring and compare it to the success log on Edge. Will update when I hear back

UPDATE!: This is super embarrassing, I'm going to look like a noob. I fixed my error by making sure I had HTTPS - quite hard as you'd assume x.yyyy.zzz (which would redirect to the login, but not show a page to confirm HTTPS) would automatically use HTTPS if enabled on the server, typing it manually fixed. I've updated my .htaccess to force HTTPS so this error cannot occur

It confirms why Edge works as well - Since I've used that page with Https before, it had that saved and automatically used that while chrome, IE and safari I never used for this URL before.

Hope this is the answer you're looking for!